# Calculating the flux of a vector field.

Tags: integration, vector-analysis, vector-fields, line-integrals

Let $S$ be the unit sphere $x^2+y^2+z^2=1$ with the outward pointing normal vector **n**. Calculate the flux for the vector field $\mathbf{f}(\mathbf{r})=4\mathbf{r}$ through $S$.

**What I have done so far:**

I have rearranged the equation to get $z=\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}$ and thus $N(x,y)=(\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}},1)$

Now to calculate the flux the equation is $\iint\limits_{S}\mathbf{f}\cdot\mathbf{n}dS$.

Hence I now have $$4\iint\limits_{S}(x,y, \sqrt{1-x^2-y^2} )\cdot (\frac{x}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}},\frac{y}{\sqrt{1-x^2-y^2}},1)dS$$

$$=4\iint\limits_{S}\frac{1}{\sqrt{-x^2-y^2+1}}dxdy$$

However I don't know how to get the limits for the integral.

Comment: This problem will be vastly easier if you switch to spherical coordinates.

Comment: https://mathworld.wolfram.com/SphericalCoordinates.html

Comment: It should be either
$$2 \iint_D \boldsymbol f \cdot \nabla(z - f(x, y)) \, dx dy,$$
where $D$ is the unit disk (in the $xy$-plane), or
$$\iint_{\mathcal S} \boldsymbol f \cdot \hat {\boldsymbol n} \, dS,$$
where $\mathcal S$ is the unit sphere and $\hat {\boldsymbol n}$ is the unit normal (and the area element $dS$ for $\mathcal S$ is not the same as $dx dy$). Since $\boldsymbol r = \hat {\boldsymbol n}$ on $\mathcal S$, the latter integral gives $4 \iint_{\mathcal S} dS$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In spherical coordinates,

$x = r \cos \theta \sin \phi, y = r \sin \theta \sin \phi, z = r \cos \phi$

Surface area element $dS = r^2 \sin \phi \ d \theta d \phi = \sin \phi \ d \theta d \phi \, $ (as $r = 1$)

Please note the outward normal vector should be a unit vector pointing directly away from the origin for this surface. So using, $\vec{r} = x \hat{i} + y\hat{j} + z\hat{k} = \cos \theta \sin \phi \, \hat{i} + \sin \theta \sin \phi \, \hat{j} + \cos \phi \,\hat{k}$

$\hat{n} = \frac{\vec{r}}{||r||} = \cos \theta \sin \phi \, \hat{i} + \sin \theta \sin \phi \, \hat{j} + \cos \phi \,\hat{k}$

$\vec{F} = 4r = 4(\cos \theta \sin \phi \, \hat{i} + \sin \theta \sin \phi \, \hat{j} + \cos \phi \,\hat{k})$

$Flux = \displaystyle \iint_S \vec{F} \cdot \hat{n} dS$

$ \displaystyle = 4 \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} (\cos \theta \sin \phi \, \hat{i} + \sin \theta \sin \phi \, \hat{j} + \cos \phi \,\hat{k}) \cdot (\cos \theta \sin \phi \, \hat{i} + \sin \theta \sin \phi \, \hat{j} + \cos \phi \,\hat{k}) \sin \phi \, d\theta d\phi$

$ \displaystyle = 4 \int_0^{\pi} \int_0^{2\pi} \sin \phi d\theta d\phi = 16 \pi$

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{\bbx}[1]{\,\bbox[15px,border:1px groove navy]{\displaystyle{#1}}\,}
 \newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\on}[1]{\operatorname{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$
$\ds{\bbox[5px,#ffd]{}}$

---

\begin{align}
&\bbox[5px,#ffd]{\left.\int 4\vec{r}\cdot\dd\vec{S}
\,\right\vert_{\ r\ =\ 1}} =
4\int r\,\hat{r}\cdot\pars{\hat{r}\verts{\dd\vec{S}} \over r^{2}} =
4\int\overbrace{r}^{\ds{1}}\,\,
\overbrace{\hat{r}\cdot\hat{r}}^{\ds{1}}\
\overbrace{{\verts{\dd\vec{S}} \over r^{2}}}^{\ds{\dd\Omega_{\,\vec{r}}}}
\\[5mm] = &\
4\ \underbrace{\int\dd\Omega_{\,\vec{r}}}_{\ds{4\pi}}\
=\ \bbx{16\,\pi} \\ &
\end{align}